# Слоги в слове Виктор

Tags: фонетика, слоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно разделить на слоги слово *Виктор* и почему так, а не иначе.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Если это для **школьного** разбора, то по закону восходящей звучности: Ви-ктор, если в транскрипции, то пишется в квадратных скобках и с маленькой буквы.

Слог как основная звуковая единица русского языка строится по закону восходящей звучности: в пределах слога звуки располагаются от наименее звучного к наиболее звучному. Слогораздел проходит в месте наибольшего спада звучности. Наиболее звучными являются гласные (Г), затем в порядке уменьшающейся звучности идут сонорные (С), затем шумные (Ш) согласные. Отсюда следует несколько правил деления слов на фонетические слоги.

1. Г—ШШГ
   Сочетание шумных согласных между гласными отходит к последующему слогу: про-стой, зве-зда, ло-дка.
2. Г—ШСГ
   Сочетание шумного согласного с сонорным между гласными отходит к последующему слогу: до-бро, ве-сло, до-гма.
3. ГС—ШГ
   Сочетание сонорного согласного с шумным между гласными имеет слогораздел внутри этого сочетания: пар-та, кол-ба, лом-кий, брон-за.
4. Гj—ШГ, Гj—СГ
   Сочетание звука [j] с шумным или сонорным между гласными имеет слогораздел внутри этого сочетания: лей-ка, вой-дём, кай-ма, сай-ра.
5. Г—ССГ
   Сочетание сонорных согласных между гласными отходит к последующему слогу: ко-рма, то-мный.

Answer (score 1):

На ваш вопрос в текущей формулировке невозможно дать научный ответ. Существуют различные теории слогораздела, и выбор какой-то одной — дело исследователя.

Хотите — разделяйте так: Ви-ктор (можете сказать, что это согласуется с теорией М. В. Ломоносова, широко практикуемой в школе, правда, в усеченном виде; или с теорией Р. И. Аванесова; теорией Л. В. Бондарко).

Хотите по-другому — Вик-тор (артикуляционная теория Л. В. Щербы; теория сонорности, доработанная М. В. Пановым).

Выбирайте.